# Override open value from primary constructor

Tags: kotlin

Imagine I have class like this:

```
open class CSRequest<Data : Any>(open val onSend: () -> CSResponse<Data>) {
// some other code
}
```

I would like to be able to override it sometimes so I can write something like:

```
class SpecialRequest(items: List<String>) : CSRequest<CSServerData>() {
    override val onSend: () -> CSResponse<CSServerData> = {
        // Do send work
    }
}
```

But I cannot. This is my api. I am asking, if I can somehow design class CSRequest, so the value onSend will be overridable by extending class CSRequest but at the same time passable as constructor parameter.

Comment: What you want doesn't make sense, if you are specifying the function is the constructor why would you want to override it?? it sounds redundant

Comment: @OmarMainegra redundant what where ? I just want to give options to how class CSRequest can be used. I want to be able to extend it and also to use it as I use it already, by supplying function as argument. But when extending it its not  convenient to pass there function as argument because you lose context of extended class there. Its also not too much readable ... Well i can make another subclass like CSRequestBase or whatever but didn't want to go this way as I have seen that kotlin allows some play with overriding of arguments so was curious if there is some other way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The superclass constructor expects an argument of type `() -> CSResponse<Data>`. So the subclass must pass such a value when invoking the super constructor, and doesn't need to override anything.

Since you haven't post the code of the classes used in your snippet, I'll take a simple example:

```
class CSResponse<D>(val body: D)
class CSServerData

open class CSRequest<Data : Any>(open val onSend: () -> CSResponse<Data>) {
    // some other code
}

class SpecialRequest(items: List<String>) : CSRequest<CSServerData>({ CSResponse(CSServerData()) })
```

Comment: I was asking, if I can somehow deign class CSRequest, so the value onSend will be overridable by extending class CSRequest but at the same time passable as constructor parameter. I will add this to question, looks like it was not clear.